# Accessing Context in a CountDownTimer enclosed scope

Tags: java, android, android-context, countdowntimer

I'm making a `SplashActivity` and I encountered a problem when I want to pass the `SplashActivity` context into a static function that run inside a `CountDownTimer` enclosed scope using `this` keyword and `getBaseContext()` method.

**TL;DR**

I am trying to figure out how to access `SplashActivity` context inside an enclosed scope, that is `CountDownTimer`.

**What I have tried:**

1. **`SplashActivity temp = this`**

   I have made a `SplashActivity temp = this;` declaration on `onCreate` method of the `Activity`, but decided this will not be effective for all `Activity` that I have made, since I must declare `Activity` for each `Activity` class that I have made.
2. **`Context temp = this.getBaseContext();`**

   Basically same as above, but more flexible for all the `Activity` but in my opinion is still not effective for the program.
3. **`ClassName.staticFunction(super.getBaseContext());`**

   This will not work because `CountDownTimer` doesn't `extends` from `SplashActivity`, although this kind of solution is the one I was looking for.

**Codes:**

*SplashActivity.java*

```java
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        new CountDownTimer(3000,100) {
            //...
            public void onFinish() {
                MainActivity.StartActivity( SplashActivity.getBaseContext() );
                //SplashActivity. will throw an error, must replace
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public static void StartActivity(Context mContext) {
        Intent act = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(act);
    }
}
```

**What I expect:**

Run `MainActivity.StartActivity(something.getBaseContext)` in `SplashActivity` `CountDownTimer` without creating any additional variable (because memory optimization), creates a `MainActivity` view.

Comment: At moments like this, I really wished Java had `pointers` like in C++

Comment: Can you try to use  `MainActivity.StartActivity(this@SplashActivity);`?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen Unfortunately, it didn't work, although I wish this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I am using this solution:

```java
final Context self = this;
```

Which is inserted in:

```java
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context self = this; // HERE
        //...
        new CountDownTimer(3000,100) {
            public void onFinish() {
                MainActivity.StartActivity( self ); //HERE
    ...
```